# Compiler for LaTeX

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

### Problem:

Given a string representing a mathematical expression with constants (pi, e, psi, i), basic arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /), parentheses, fractions, and exponentiation, write a program or function to convert a string to its equivalent LaTeX code. The input string will only contain digits, arithmetic operators, parentheses, spaces, and constants.

###### Example:

- **`Input:`** `2 + (3 * π) / (4 - e)^2`
- **`Output:`** `$2 + \frac{3\cdot\pi}{(4 - e)^2}$`
- **`Input:`** `π * 22/7 - 9.81`
- **`Output:`** `$\pi\cdot\frac{22}{7} - 9.81$`
- **`Input:`** `2 - e^i + 3^(32)*(2*ψ)/(7*π)`
- **`Output:`** `$2 - e^i + 3^{32}\cdot\frac{2\cdot\psi}{7\cdot\pi}$`

#### Constraints:

- 0 < `Input string` < 100 chars.
- You need to implement fractions using the `\frac{}{}` command in LaTeX.

#### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

#### Latex commands:

- `\pi` for the constant "π".
- `\psi` for the constant "ψ".
- `e` for the constant "e".
- `i` for the constant "i".
- `\cdot` for multiplication.
- `\frac{}{}` for fractions.
- `^` operator for exponentiation. "{}" for exponents are optional.
- The output should be enclosed in "$" or "$$" to indicate a math expression in LaTeX.

Comment: (-1) IMO This is a chameleon challenge for “parse a numerical expression”, which has been done to death. The formatting of the expression as LaTeX is easy, the parsing is the hard part. My suggestion would be to allow the input to be taken as a pre-parsed expression. (By parsed I mean as a tree or similar structure with operator precedence, parentheses, etc established).

Comment: It’s possible some solutions won’t need to entirely parse the input but I think it’s at least partially necessary

Comment: Why is `3 * π` `3\cdot\pi` and not `3\pi`?

Comment: @Neil because its `3 * pi` ;if it was `3pi` then it would be `3\pi`

Comment: @noodleman I'd argue parsing is the most important part. mainly the `frac{}{}` operation otherwise this problem is as easy as just ``string.replace("*", "\cdot")``

Comment: I am looking forward to the answers!

Comment: Is `${(4 - e)}^2$` acceptable for `(4 - e)^2`?.

Comment: @Neil that would move the exponent from the denominator to outside the fraction, changing meaning.

Comment: @Neil $$2 + \frac{3\cdot\pi}{(4 - e)^2}$$ and  $$2 + \frac{3\cdot\pi}{(4 - e)}^2$$ are not the same. The Problem in really only cares about visual representation in the end and nothing else.

Comment: @doubleunary There's no fraction in my example, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Neil right. I assumed that you were referring to the [algebraic fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_fraction) in the first example.

Comment: @doubleunary I guess that could turn into `$2 + \frac{3\cdot\pi}{{(4 - e)}^2}$`?

Comment: @Neil yeah looks good.

Comment: 1) When you say that `{}` is optional for `^`, do you mean it is optional when exponent is single digit or is it always optional regardless of exponent. 2) Does unary `-` need to be handled. 3) How should double `^` (e.g. `2^2^2`) be handled, is output of `$2^{2}^{2}$` (invalid in latex) fine or does it need to be `$2^{2^{2}}$`.

Comment: @Mukundan314 Sorry for the late reply, but the problems will always be valid latex. and yes `{}` being optional is only for single digits since I don't think there's a way to do multiple-digit exponents without them, and I don't understand what you mean by `-` since in this question it's just considered as a subtraction and it is in the test cases.

Comment: By unary `-`, I meant negative numbers and expressions like `-(2 + 2)`.

Comment: 1) Does an exponent given in parenthesis need to be output in parenthesis (is `3^(e+i)` -> `3^{e+i}` okay given input 3 does `3^(32)` -> `3^{32}`?)
2) Does the output need to preserve the spacing of the input, or is whitespace fine as long as it renders the same in LaTeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Tamsin](https://github.com/catseye/Tamsin), <sup><s>375</s> <s>220</s></sup> 211 bytes

```
1=2->E&'$'+E+'$'.2=3->R&{"/"&3->E&R<-'\\frac{'+R+'}{'+E+'}'}&(("-"|"+"|"*"&'\\cdot')->O&2->E&''+O+E)/R.3=(s&"("&2->E&")"&s&'('+E+')'|("π"&'\\pi'|"ψ"&'\\psi'|" "|$:alnum)/'')->R&("^"&3->E&'^{'+E+'}')/R.s={" "}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7BaoNAEL3nK6ZD2Jl1WSVrIW2p0ou3gOBZBElaEKoN0R6KCh7zd36S3dX2MDvz3rz3drqybqtmWQ6R0XEiaE8qUfb1TRTqOBM9BihCt8peNeX5x60896QyRWO/SkcaBTNqHFDZ8lBY1fny1ZHUcSq2VFKpSmSQ@WHErUDGjUeJohXEa5CkgXGeVv@1ogHn@za3DgAO@5fys/muZUAuOhOMxd9pVPzf4v5oo97KR3@py6qBCHp@wLxBEFA2P84NOoaThXyANzhJB1MLr7eq6dbJ6kbbiPzFgAIOwYN5khAAP4KGd1mY3TxZ0pjgaIln/@mwM25TVFYfFhwa6bHx5rsM@OhZ7y8)

Ungolfed and heavily commented version:

```python
# expr1 (entrypoint); match `expr2` (store in E); return '$' + E + '$'
expr1 = expr2 -> E & '$' + E + '$'.

# implements "/", "-", "+", "*" over expr3
expr2 = expr3 -> R                             # match `expr3`    (store in R)
      & {                                      # while possible:
          "/"                                  #   match "/"
        & expr3 -> E                           #   match `expr3`  (store in E)
        & R <- '\\frac{' + R + '}{' + E + '}'  #   R = '\frac{' + R + '}{' + E + '}'
      } & (                                    # scope (
        ("-" | "+" | "*" & '\\cdot') -> O      #   match operator (store in O)
        & expr2 -> E                           #   match `expr2`  (store in E)
        & '' + O + E                           #   '' + O + E     (implicit return)
      )/R.                                     # ) match scope zero or more times then concatenate R and matches (implicit return)

# implements "()", numbers and "^"
expr3 = (                    # scope (
            spaces           #     match `spaces`
          & "("              #     match "("
          & expr2 -> E       #     match `expr1`   (store in E)
          & ")"              #     match ")"
          & spaces           #     match `spaces`
          & '(' + E + ')'    #     '(' + E + ')'   (implicit return)
        |                    #   or
          (                  #     scope (
              "π" & '\\pi'   #          match "π"  (replace with \pi)
            | "ψ" & '\\psi'  #       or match "ψ"  (replace with \psi)
            | " "            #       or match " "
            | $:alnum        #       or match alphanumeric [0-9A-Za-z]
          )/''               #     ) match scope zero or more times then concatenate matches (implicit return)
      ) -> R                 # ) store return from scope in R
      & (                    # scope (
        "^"                  #   match "^"
        & expr3 -> E         #   match `expr3`     (store in E)
        & '^{' + E + '}'     #   '^{' + E + '}'    (implicit return)
      )/R.                   # ) match scope zero or more times then concatenate R and matches (implicit return)

spaces = {" "}.  # zero or more spaces

# command to golf and copy to clipboard:
# sed 's/paces\|expr\| \|#.*//g; s/""/" "/g' latex.tamsin | tr -d '\n' | wl-copy
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 513 bytes

```python
from re import*
R=str.replace
def F(r,c):
	while'/^*'[c]in r:
		i=r.index('/^*'[c])
		r=r[:i-1]+[['\\frac{%s}{%s}','%s^{%s}','%s \\cdot %s'][c]%((c>0)*sub('(%\d+)([}]*)$','(\\1)\\2',r[i-1])or r[i-1],r[i+1])]+r[i+2:]
	return r
P=lambda e:R(R(' '.join(F(F(F(findall('%*[.\d]+|i|e|π|ψ|\+|-|\*|/|\^',e),1),0),2)),'π','\\pi'),'ψ','\\psi')
def f(e,t=[]):
	while'('in e:
		e=sub('\(([^()]*)\)',lambda m:f'%{(len(t),t.append(P(m[1])))[0]}',e)
	z=lambda e:t and z(R(e,f'%{len(t)-1}',t.pop()))or e
	return'$%s$'%z(P(e))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLBbptAED2brxhFRjsLGMc4kVtL9Jhbq8hXFiRiFoUKA1qwmgZWyjF/509yZ7Edp60Q0s7OvLdv3kzzu3uuq@XxmKt6B0pCsWtq1TnWJmw75SvZlOlWWpnM4QGVt@Vra/LruSglmycOi7ZxUYGiu0kRKr@oMvmClwynWxWqaF3MFrEbRUyIXKXb3m61@ZnH7Db5OIEQ26zuwG5ZTGAbcfvtljvt/gkZ2iJzOUY6dviUqlGIBRciYJ6KDDmvFZxO5sKli9g1h2AdWxMlu70ikdZjWKa7pywFud7gBhkw/2ddVPgwfjmJT8sSme1EvshidygGORzehsP7INxhNghnmA8iYZ7k3oJ7t9wLOPfY4Y0ECdEUzATvp6ClaPQsR@l1YRRfbUNGjknjmAzH5gRilCCn1gRn3lnibp0zu8dSVthxr/PTppFVho@4i6g7zqPbWBsl1uT12lUHaZXBK/UmPQM/oWcLquz8pm6QgOSUvHjCpnY7ZfYr0UrOj/KlUbJti7pqIQSaVwAu4BIcOLxxmAPewQwkT8h2YFOTPA90eZmdsUH3l7o@0HrKYo9ajcgm4gmC@YpyX/0vi5HD1F@xI1cQ6H6lz0Uf6MAwJgU9uUxwGXAHA@fwzue4ckjbWY8p6Qs9FvWmSv/L/UlnS0JXf@n@eAwDF5dz4uUzxLsZvePc8/961v2IolfHfkdKfiG8/0RGmAWHBAL6yc1LNBKes8YqI3kMtIkIH1tWbqYFZl@uo6HNqfdds@9oRrRdtAi0BI0qqg5z1t98T7vt8w0UOZyqwlDSxoAsWwk3P2rYjXk9QG@gGuhwKtSMH/8A)

This took quite a while to golf down and for me to feel all right about it, but at this point I think I've done about all that I can without additional help. If we're allowed to go wild with parenthesis, then I can reduce this some more, but I'm not sure if just producing mathematically-equivalent LaTeX-accepted output is a valid solution.

The short explanation is that I use regex to replace inner parenthetical expressions with a meta token, inserting the LaTeX-ed version of that minimal expression into a work list, and after all parenthetical statements are replaced with meta tokens I go back and replace each meta token with its processed form, resulting in the fully LaTeX formatted string.

Full explanation:

```python
# Needed for re.sub and re.findall
import re

'''
Parameters:	array - An array of tokens, or expressions, representing the current expression
		index - 0 for division, 1 for exponentiation, 2 for multiplication
Formats the provided array in one of three ways
    - Start by finding the index of the requested character
    - While that character is still a lone element in the array
        - Get the index of the requested opertor
        - Get the values on either side of the operator
        - Set the replacement string as appropriate for the operator
	    - If the operation is exponentiation or multiplication, we need to wrap the lefthand operand in parenthesis if it was a meta token (denoted by a token of the form '%<d>')
	- Replace indices (i - 1, i, and i + 1) with the LaTeX string representing the operation, and format the string to insert the formatted left and righthand sides
'''
def Format(array, index):
	c = '/^*'[index]	# Get the character we're doing formatting for
	while c in array:	# Do this until all standalone c have been formatted
		i = array.index('/^*'[index])		# Get the index into the list of c
		replacement = ''			# Placeholder for the text replacement
		l, r = array[i - 1], array[i + 1]	# The left and righthand sides of the operator

		# If division, insert l and r as-is in the {}'s
		if c == '/':
			replacement = '\\frac{%s}{%s}'

		# If exponentiation, we need to wrap the lefthand side with
		#  parenthesis iff it's a meta token (of the form '%\d+')
		elif c == '^':
			replacement = '%s^{%s}'
			# Find all occurrences of '%\d+' in array[i - 1]
			l = re.sub('(%\d+)([}]*)$', '(\\1)\\2', array[i-1])

		# If multiplication, we need to wrap the lefthand side with
		#  parenthesis iff it's a meta token (of the form '%\d+')
		elif c == '*':
			replacement='%s \\cdot %s'
			l = re.sub('(%\d+)([}]*)$', '(\\1)\\2', array[i-1])

		# Replace indices (i - 1, i, i + 1) with the LaTeX string,
		#  inserting our formatted left and righthand sides
		array = array[:i-1] + [replacement % (l, r)] + array[i+2:]
	
	# Return array as-is
	return array

# Takes a string expression of tokens and operators, and returns the string
#  representation of its LaTeX formatting
def Process(e):
	array = re.findall('%*[.\d]+|i|e|π|ψ|\+|-|\*|/|\^',e)	# Split the string into all valid tokens
	array = Format(array, 1)		# Format the list for exponentiation
	array = Format(array, 0)		# Format the list for division
	array = Format(array, 2)		# Format the list for multiplication
	string = ' '.join(array)		# Join all of the tokens in the expression
	string = string.replace('π','\\pi')	# Replace π with LaTeX command
	string = string.replace('ψ','\\psi')	# Replace ψ with LaTeX command
	return string				# Return the processed string

# The main function that performs the conversion
# Takes an expression, and uses a provided list to do work
def f(e, t=[]):
	# Define an inner function to hand to re.sub
	def helper(m):
		l = len(t)		# Get the current length of t
		t.append(Process(m[1]))	# Append the processed form of our matched group
		return f'%{l}'		# Return a meta token referencing the index in t we just added

	# While there are parenthesis still to parse through
	while '(' in e:
		# Find all occurrences of parenthesis with no parenthesis inside them
		#  and pass them to helper. This will replace an expression of the form
		#     (2 / ψ)
		#  with a meta token of the form
		#     %D
		#  where t[D] holds the LaTeX formatted representation of the expression
		#     t[D] = '\\frac{2}{\\psi}'
		e = re.sub('\(([^()]+)\)', helper, e)

	# Since we only processed sub-expressions, process the remainder
	e = Process(e)

	# Go through and replace each meta token with its true value
	# Since we added them 0->len(t)-1, we replace in reverse order
	#  by popping the values off of t
	while t:
		# Replace '%i' with the i-th value of t in our expression
		e = e.replace(f'%{len(t) - 1}', t.pop())

	# Finally wrap the expression in $'s and return
	return f'${e}$'
```

Comment: Very nice Indeed!